# why does void method do not work with system.debug

Tags: apex

Void methods like below does not work with system.debug... why ?

```
List<String> myStrings = new List<String> { 'one', 'two','Three','four'};
mystring.sort();
system.debug ('----' + mystrings) // works
but....... 
system.debug('------' + mystring.sort()); // does not work because method return the void....
```

Answer (score 2):

With the `+` you're saying that you'll be appending something to the existing string `'-------'`. You can't append a void to a string. You can't also debug a void. The name itself tells you that it's a void (doesn't return anything).

You should be calling the method and then outputing the result list:

```
List<String> myStrings = new List<String> { 'one', 'two','Three','four'};
myStrings.sort();
system.debug(myStrings);
```